# Is ex-procedural a word?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

I am looking for a single word for the expression, "outside normal procedures."  I have tried ex-procedural, but it sounds too formal.

Comment: extra-procedural, not ex. Ex means from the place of. extra is outside of. As in: extra-judicial.

Comment: "anticonformist" or less formal "maverick". Please, provide the sentence where the term would fit.

Comment: "Unconventional" or "nontraditional" are also possibilities, but it's hard to say without knowing the context.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix *extra-*, as in *extraterrestrial, extracurricular activities* or an *extramarital affair*, is commonly used to signal ‘outside of…’ The word *extraprocedural*, sometimes with a hyphen, denotes activities outside the official procedings of a deliberative or judicial body or of established procedures.

> In Congress, positive committee power must rely on more than formal procedure, and many [*extraprocedural*](https://books.google.de/books?id=MjtQAQAAIAAJ&q=extraprocedural&dq=extraprocedural&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBoYGe3LXbAhWGCywKHVU4A24Q6AEIVjAI) resources advantage committees.  — Steven S. Smith, *Call to Order: Floor Politics in the House and Senate*,  1989, 174.
>
> On the contrary, there is evidence to suggest that [*extra-procedural*](https://books.google.de/books?id=iFhbAAAAIAAJ&q=extraprocedural&dq=extraprocedural&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4y_SC3rXbAhViMJoKHT9eApE4WhDoAQhDMAg) tactics were being employed to oust Obote. It would seem that Obote's opponents had not ruled out violent means.  — *New Guinea and Australia, the Pacific and South-East Asia*, 1970.
>
> In conclusion, a rereading of the archival documents shows once more that all those involved in the trial, without exception, have a right to the benefit of good faith, in the absence of [*extra-procedural*](https://books.google.de/books?id=HthXAAAAYAAJ&q=extraprocedural&dq=extraprocedural&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivid6T37XbAhXCsaQKHexVAQ84bhDoAQhCMAc) documents showing the contrary.  — Luigi Accattoli, *When a Pope Asks Forgiveness*, 1998.

Whether the procedure you are discussing warrants the use of this word depends on what it is. If you’re talking about a law court, legislative body, or established medical or scientific procedures, you should consider it. Otherwise, outside the usual procedure or guidelines, outside established protocol, etc. might be more apt.